# Python - How to plot a 2D graph by considering all combinations?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, vector, combinations

I have the following question in python : I have  7 lists(can be even a simple row or column vector)  each one with same number of elements .For example :

`a = [x1,x2,....xn]` where xi is a float

`b= [y1,y2,.....yn]` where yi is a float

`...........`

`g = [z1,z2,... zn]`   where zi is a float

What I need to do is :

First to find all possible combinations of these seven lists without repetitions (I know there is itertools.combinations) in groups of two (I must find 21 possible combinations). For example (a,b) , (a,c), (a,d)....

Second ,once I get all these combinations I can run a sort of for cycle to plot all these 21 graps in 2D (plot(a,b), plot(a,c),...plot(f,g)). 
I was thinking something like list of lists, but I am wondering if there is something ready in some library or even easier.
Thanks!

**EDIT**
@FHTMitchell 
Look at this simple example, I only get one chart if `plt.show()` is not indented

```
mydata = np.array([[1.4,2.5,3.7],[4.34,5.92,6.234],[2.34,5.12,62.234],[44.34,90.92,23.234],[65.34,44.92,16.234]]) 
col1 = mydata[:,0] 
col2= mydata[:,1] 
col3 = mydata[:,2] 
for pair in itertools.combinations((col1,col2,col3), 2): 
    print(list(pair))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ax.scatter(pair[0], pair[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: is [seaborn's `pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html?highlight=pairplot#seaborn.pairplot) what you are looking for?

Comment: @DizietAsahi actually what OP said was that he need 21 graphs but with-pair plot we get 49 graphs

Comment: @AlbinPaul points out that `pairplot` produces more graphs than requested. However, you can use the underlying [`PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html#seaborn.PairGrid) and `map_lower()` or `map_upper()` to generate the required number of plots

Answer (score 3):

The solutions you expressed sounds fine to me:

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for pair in itertools.combinations((a,b,c,d,e,f,g), 2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(pair[0], pair[1])
plt.show()
```

This plots 21 individual figures. You could use `fig.save` to save them or use some other usage of `plt.subplots` to put them on the same figure.

### Edit

If you want to give each a label on the same plot, you'd have to give them a name:

```
# use dict key as name
d = dict(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f, g=g)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for (xk, xv), (yk, yv) in itertools.combinations(d.items(), 2):
    ax.scatter(xv, yv, label=f'({xk}, {yk})')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess you wanted to put  plt.show() inside the for cycle .Otherwise I get an error. Is it correct? Another question: How can I figure out which combination is going to plot?

Comment: Is there any way to put a-label , b-label and so on for each scatter?

Comment: It's something what I was looking for it! :) I'll be trying later ...Backing on first code , can you confirm that last row's code should be indented inside for cycle?Otherwise it plots just one chart that is latest combination.

Comment: Do you mean the `plt.show()` in the first code block? No, that shouldn't be indented. At least on my system, all plots are produced.

Comment: Yes, in the latest row of the first code. If not indented, I only get one chart by representing the last combination. I tried to write down an example in here ,but I'm having issues in the formatting it

Comment: It's probably your matplotlib settings being different from mine. Try putting `plt.ion()` at the top of your script

Comment: I just tried as you said, nothing has changed.I also updated the matplotlib to latest version ,no luck...!

Answer (score 3):

Try using seaborn library.

I'd import those arrays into a pandas dataframe and then plot those using PairGrid. The most simple one is generated like this:

```
sns.pairplot(df)
```

This will give you a scatter plot matrix of all possible combinations between variables:

[The plot matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3I7z.png)

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot